# Draw a curve joining a set of points in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, math, geometry

I have a set of points extracted from an image. I need to join these points to from a smooth curve. After drawing the curve on the image, I need to find the tangent to the curve and represent it on the image. I looked at cv2.approxPolyDP but it already requires a curve??

Answer (score 0):

You can build polyline, if order of points is defined. Then it is possible to simplify this polyline with [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm (if number of points is too large). Then you can construct some kind of [spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) to create smooth curve.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is related to the points being extracted in random order, the tool you need is probably the so called 2D alpha-shape. It is a generalization of the convex hull and will let you trace the "outline" of your set of points, and from there perform interpolation.

Comment: A picture would be helpful to tell if a simpler approach is possible